# How to use google analytics from jade file

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, pug

I want to track the users of my website. Since I do not have an old fashioned HTML file, should I adapt the given code to the jade syntax or can i leave the script untouched and include it somehow?

In case I need to convert it to jade syntax, can this be auto generated by some tool.

```
<script>
   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'domain.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, added a different way to do this. hope it helps you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution was easy.

Step 1: i created a file called 'analytics.js' and placed the code between the script tags in it. No conversion to jade syntax needed.

Step 2: i referenced the script from the jade file

```
script(src='/js/analytics.js')
```

Comment: This is not a great solution. Now you have to send a file over the wire just for analytics. Inlining would be much better.

Comment: Agreed, inlining is a better approach than calling an entire separate file.

Comment: OTOH, if the Google analytics script ever changes this is way easier and way more robust to update.

Comment: This worked fine for me. I don't think that inlining it would be a good solution all the time. I am just using it on a very small site though.

Comment: If you're inlining a master view page, you're good to go, one place to change ;-)

Answer (score 54):

Instead of having it look for another code file and load it. Inline (like Trevor suggested is better).

In order to accomplish this you have to make use of the `script.` tag.... not just `script`

See below:

```
script.
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-11111111-1', 'yourdomain.com');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Make sure the spacing and such is actually indented one tab from your stuff

Comment: Not working for me, google tag assistant says, 'analytics code avaialble' but not executing. 'No httpresponse detected'

Comment: Make sure your spacing is consistent

Answer (score 7):

As said here before - putting the GA snippet inline in your files is recommended, as the GA snippet will actually call another file (www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js), so it's a bit of a waste to GET another js file which will then GET the Google one.

However - if you do want to keep your layout.jade clean (and you should), you can put the code snippet BRogers wrote (the one that starts with "script.") , in a separate file, call it googleAnalytics.jade, and in your layout.jade just include :

```
include partials/googleAnalytics
```

(of course partials is the way I folder my views, that's up to you)

This will mean the GA snippet will be included in your pages on the server, saving you the additional GET, but still keeping your layout.jade nice and tidy.

Answer (score 6):

**2019 GTag Update**

The traditional GA script is replaced by this new GTAG Script

```
script(async='', src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-11111111-1')
script.
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'UA-11111111-1');
```

Answer (score 3):

Now it is Pug. Nonetheless. 
You can just include .html file with all google analytics code.

```
include includes/google_analytics.html
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you still want to add it inline way, [here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/antlis/56cd3963182ebaeadec55a23efbb60f9), I use 4 spaces for indentation. You can call it like this `+ga('yourid12345')`

Also here is the [pug google analytics mixin](https://gist.github.com/antlis/af490c77864dfca8ad6e602abb107df1), that will output the same script as you can find in [HTML5 boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate).